# sendEmail script will only sometimes send mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sometimes I can get it to automatically send when the time changes, and sometimes the script runs but no email is sent.  If a cell in Row O says "TRUE" (from the formula), and it doesn't work, I can manually type "TRUE" and it will suddenly work on all cells with the value "TRUE", even if the other cells have "TRUE" populated by a formula.  It seems so random that I don't know what works and what doesn't work.  It's been perfect multiple days in a row, and then all of a sudden it stops.  I have no idea.

I use time based triggers. Because I want it sent at a specific time, I use the 30 minute timer (which is close enough). The cell I reference only turns true if the cell in x row does not = “EMAIL_SENT” which I guess is an odd way of approaching it. It works though, because if it does send the email it turns to “FALSE”. That formula works perfectly. My problem is with getting it to always send when the value = TRUE

My script:

```
function sendEmails(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id")
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var startRow = 1;

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastrow, lastcolumn);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
  var T = 'TRUE'

  var i = 1;
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var msgHtml = '<HTML><BODY>' + 'Hello again,<p>This is a reminder that you are scheduled to participate in our paid driving study! The upcoming driving session that you are scheduled for is<b> ' + values[i][3] + ' </b>at<b> ' + values[i][4] + ' </b>at ' + 'ADDRESS' + '. The session will last approximately 4.5 hours, but be prepared for an additional 60 minutes of time required. Please plan to stay for the entire session.' + '<b>You are required to bring proof of insurance and your valid drivers license with you to your session.</b></p>' + '<font color="blue"><mark>Please respond to this email as soon as possible to confirm your attendance at this session.</mark></font>' + ' If you must cancel or reschedule your session, we require at least 24 hours advanced notice. Failure to give 24 hours advanced notice will result in a suspension from further participation. Your participation is very valuable to this study, and each driving session is crucial to our research. </p><p> Please be aware that cancellations may be made by our team for extraneous circumstances(e.g., inclement weather, construction,etc). If any of these circumstances do occur, we will let you know as soon as possible. We will do our best to rescheule you, but we cannot make any guarantees. If you have any questions, please let me know.</p>' + '<font color="red"><b>Please refer to the specific instructions provided in the scheduling email (i.e., "scheduled for L2 Driving Sessions") AND review these reminders:</b></font>' + '<p>1. Get plenty of rest and receive a healthy amount of sleep the night before your driving session<br>2. Do not drink alcohol or use any substance that may impair your driving the night before and morning of your driving session <br>3. Wash your hair within 12 hours before your session (i.e., if your session is at 1pm, you should wash your hair after 1am the previous night and before your 1pm session) <br>4. Do not put on makeup or any heavy skin products <br>5. Wear a loose-fitting shirt <br>6. Leave early so that you have enough time to find parking, go to the bathroom, etc. before your session starts</br></p>' + 'See you on<b> ' + values[i][3] + '</b>!' + '</BODY></HTML>';
    var subject = 'Driving Study ' + values[i][3] + ' at ' + values[i][4];

    if (values[i][14] == T) { 
      MailApp.sendEmail({ to: emailAddress, subject: subject, htmlBody: msgHtml});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }  
  }
}
```

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1314Q2H_n4qtq-mK3UBbtuzQzhPZpPaVm6cpxklOPsbs/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the execution transcript. It "completes", but doesn't get to the if statement that actually sends the email.

```
[18-08-28 10:59:45:401 PDT] Starting execution
[18-08-28 10:59:45:510 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([10RCcnc22RYRaf3wQhMzPp_q3f1_-LBsm2tQjYrd0h1s]) [0.099 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:45:511 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:45:512 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet([Sheet]) [0 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:45:883 PDT] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.37 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:096 PDT] Range.getDisplayValues() [0.212 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:188 PDT] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.088 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:373 PDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.184 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:374 PDT] Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 447, 15]) [0 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:692 PDT] Range.getValues() [0.317 seconds]
[18-08-28 10:59:46:708 PDT] Execution succeeded [1.294 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: When you check Stackdriver logging, do you see any error messages? (You can adjust the date span to cover a month or so)

Comment: When the script was working, I got the error "failed to send email".  This makes sense, because it would go through the entire spreadsheet and fail to send an email when it got to the first line without data.  As of now, I am getting no errors.  I will add the execution transcript to the original question- it "completes", but it doesn't get to the if statement which actually sends the email.

Comment: consider adding a line to log the values you are checking: `console.log({message: "values[][14] values", v14: values.map(function (row) { return row[14]; }) });` before you begin your `for` loop. This will send the array to Stackdriver so you can verify the trigger is running, and that the values are what you expect.

Comment: The values were what I expected the first time, but when I added more lines and triggered it again the values were all FALSE even though there was a TRUE. So the email didn’t send. I don’t understand what’s happening.

Comment: UPDATE- time based triggers aren’t working, but on change and on edit is fine. I had time based triggers working before, so I don’t know what changed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you run this script, but it sounds like you've installed an edit trigger for it. Consider removing the edit trigger and then re-adding it. Note that such a trigger only executes when a human modifies the Sheets file - not when formulas change. This is by design, and will not change.

[Review more about Google Apps Script & triggers in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). You may find a time-based trigger more useful if you need the emails to be dispatched without user interaction. Note that your script currently makes no use of the flag set in each row after an email is sent - you probably want to check that when looking at the row, e.g.

```
if (values[i][7] == EMAIL_SENT)
  continue;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I use time based triggers. Because I want it sent at a specific time, I use the 30 minute timer (which is close enough). The cell I reference only turns true I’d  the cell in x row  does not = “EMAIL_SENT” which I guess is an odd way of approaching it. It works though, because if it does send the email it turns to “FALSE”. That formula works perfectly. My problem is with getting it to always send when the value = TRUE

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to include that information.